# New API for removed methods in Java OpenCV 3.0

Tags: java, opencv3.0

This methods was removed in the new API. How do they look like in OpenCV 3.0 Java?

```
Mat imageHSV = new Mat(image.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
Mat imageBlurr = new Mat(image.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);

new Mat(image.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_ALL);

Mat imageA =new Mat(image.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_ALL);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking...

Comment: @ankhzet , the question becomes obvious when you try to update old code to a new one :)

Answer (score 3):

With OpenCV 3.0 you can do it like this:

```
        Mat imageHSV = new Mat(mRgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat imageBlurr = new Mat(mRgba.size(),CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat imageA = new Mat(mRgba.size(), CvType.CV_32F);
```